# cannot open one website in any browser

Tags: website, connection

Since two days ago I cannot open one website in any browser (Mozilla, IE, Chrome, Opera) on my private computer. I've cleaned cash, reset the modem, my provider told me that everything is ok with site on other computers (I can open it everywhere else), but it continuously says: "The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments. Etc." What should I do to make it work? Tnx!

Comment: Can you `ping` the website? How about `traceroute`? Have you tried looking at the packets with Wireshark? Are you running any firewall or antivirus software that may be interfering?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an internet connection at all? Do other programs besides browsers have connections? Can you ping anything? If any of those answers are yes, perhaps your proxy settings are messed up. If no, you need to solve your connection problem and this isn't about browsers.

Comment: Internet connection is ok, I can read everything else beside that page. I've tried with shutting down firewall and antivirus and it all stay the same.

Comment: Did you look into your system proxy settings like I suggested? That would be the next thing because it affects how all browsers on a system attempt to connect.

Comment: How should I exactly check this proxy settings?

Comment: Hmm...proxy settings seem to be browser specific in windows. Sorry I was making assumptions based on \*nix. If more than one browser is having trouble, you likely have a firewall issue unless you have some special program other installed.

Comment: I've put no proxy option in Mozilla but it still stay the same. Firewall is from Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Is website online at all?

Check here: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Comment: Yes, it's available from any other computer.

Comment: Check the hosts file. And flush dns cache (ipconfig /flushdns)